# Regex Assistance with Power shell - Filter and display correct information

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I am working in powershell to filter and display items with "[N/A]" in the row located from a CSV

Below are the items on the CSV under  "Summary" Tab

```
1) 629eda518c07d4012e04000034285c07.httpprxp.dll with hash [N/A] was executed on PC\KTD1234.
2) 6d4d73457f07d4011c0a0000b410742c.utcutil.dll with hash [N/A] was executed on PC\KTD1234.
3) 1qx4e22r.bp3.ps1 with hash [ca8a261820bf6a2a75390168e9e7264c396bfc689047ecd08f87df05c50dc72d] was executed on PC\KTD1234.
```

The code below is what I have but it does not appear to display the N/A items

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Users\DS\Desktop\Scripts\Remove NA.csv" -Header "Summary" -Delimiter :  
foreach ($thing in $CSV){Write-Host $thing.Summary |  
 where  {$_.Summary -contains  '\[N/A\]'} }
```

There are thousands of items on this sheet so I assume regex is the way to do this. Is there a better way to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

While it does not violate the CSV standard per se the data you presented isn't really a CSV. You can just use Get-Content then use -match to filter:

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\DS\Desktop\Scripts\Remove NA.csv" | Where-Object{$_ -match ' \[N/A\] '}
```

Comment: Well then the example data you provided is incomplete. I took the data you provided, saved it in a file, used this code and it ouptu line 1 and 2 but not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Saving an ?Excel? sheet as csv doesn't make it a csv - at least not a well formed one.

I see it as a plain text file and would treat it as such.

See `get-help about_comparison_operators` -contains is not RegEx based but literal

If you want to **remove** lines matching `[N/A]` change your where from -contains to -notmatch with the escaped `'\[N/A\]'`

Comment: The service we uses export it as a CSV file. I am  trying to display the values with the [N/A]. I can worry about exporting another time

Comment: Well the file name `Remove NA.csv` is a bit misleading. Then change `-contains` to `-match`